# iframe parent javascript variable access

Tags: javascript

I have a large application that utilizes iframes a lot. It sets a lot of variables in the main page and then the iframe references / changes them similar to

```
parent.mode = 'save'
```

Now it was written a while back and works fine in ie, but in modern browsers like chrome this errors all over the place, debugging it down to the parent calls.

I'm wondering if there is a new cross browser safe way of forcing the application access parent variables.

I'd rather not rewrite the entire application and not break IE functionality as most users are IE users.

Comment: I know for a fact that `parent.` variable access and writing works in Chrome. Are you sure that the errors are not from another source?

Comment: The full line is
`parent.Mode.value = Mode;`
And parent.mode is a hidden form field which does exist

Comment: Javascript is case-sensitive. `parent.Mode` and `parent.mode` mean different things. Also, is there an element in the document whose `id` is `mode`? If so, it might be in the global scope overwriting something.

Comment: What do the Chrome errors say on that line? We can't really tell you what the problem is if we don't know the context or what the error says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I worked it out, the input tag on the parent had name="blah" but no it, works in ie, but in chrome, I needed the Id.

```
<input type="hidden" name="nuMode" value="New" />
```

became

```
<input type="hidden" name="nuMode" id="nuMode" value="New" />
```

Thanks for the pointers, once I realised parent was fine, I went searching deeper.

Comment: On a side note these fields are NOT in a form. They seem only to set javascript variables. The developer tells me there is a reason it was done like this but can't remember why. I would just change them to `nuMode = 'New';` but it might break something.